# Open a tab next to the active tab in Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to open a new tab right next to the active tab in a firefox add-on. Here is my code:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.google.com");
```

This opens the new tab at the end of the tab list. I couldn't figure out how to force it to position the new tab immediately after the active tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of the current tab, then set the index of the new tab to that `+ 1`

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var index = tabs.activeTab.index;
tabs.open("http://www.google.com");
tabs.activeTab.index = index + 1;
```

Alternatively, if you look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#open%28options%29), you'll see that there's a constructor parameter called

> inBackground: boolean. If present and true, the new tab will be opened to the right of the active tab and will not be active.

By combining this with the onOpen event, you can achieve the desired effect:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  inBackground: true,
  onOpen: function(tab) {
    tab.activate();
  }
});
```

I haven't tested either of these, so some debugging might be needed.

Comment: Thank you. The first one works.Second one has the default behavior as far as tab location is concerned (new tab opens at the end). The only thing `inBackground: ture` does is background the tab.

Comment: Interesting. If that's the case, you should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes|Add-on%20SDK|Documentation) to let them know.

Comment: @MiJo and others. [This bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=715560) is worth reading if you're experiencing inconsistencies.

Comment: The first one does not work for me, probably due to tabs.open now being called asynchronously -there have been some movements in the addon sdk (2015). 
I got it working like this:
`
        var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
        var index = tabs.activeTab.index;
        tabs.open({
            url: "http://www.google.com",
            onOpen: function (tab) {
                tab.index = index+1;
            }
        });
`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [lower-level APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/loadOneTab) like [gtranslate does](https://github.com/bpierre/gtranslate/blob/5513b6172948fedad75db0e35b2da429f5077604/index.js#L139):

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils')
const browser = getMostRecentBrowserWindow().gBrowser
const tab = browser.loadOneTab(url, {relatedToCurrent: true})
browser.selectedTab = tab
```

Note that it might not work with [e10s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Multiprocess_Firefox_and_the_SDK).